# How to serialize query object with custom delimeter

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, openapi

I have yaml file:

```
openapi: 3.0.1
info:
  title: My API
  version: v1
paths:
  # /users;id=3;id=4?metadata=true
  /users:
    get:
      parameters:
        - in: query
          name: offset
          schema:
            type: integer
          description: The number of items to skip before starting to collect the result set
        - in: query
          name: limit
          schema:
            type: integer
          description: The numbers of items to return
        - in: query
          name: origin
          style: form
          explode: false
          schema:
            type: object
            properties:
              city:
                type: string
              zip:
                type: string
      responses:
        '200':
          description: A list of users
```

When I click "execute" in https://editor.swagger.io, the generated Curl looks like this:

```
curl -X GET "https://editor.swagger.io/users?offset=2&limit=12&origin=city,atlanta,zip,303" -H "accept: */*"
```

However, I need it to be like this:

```
curl -X GET "https://editor.swagger.io/users?offset=2&limit=12&origin=city:atlanta|zip:303" -H "accept: */*"
```

Is it possible to do this? I could not find any info in documentation about setting custom delimeters.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: **No**.

Your specific use case isn't covered by [serialize parameters](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/serialization/) and they follow the [rfc6570](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6570#section-3.2) - it's a good idea to follow the standard if you want to design a well accepted web api.

You specified `explode: false` and `style:form`.
When you turn `explode:true` on you will get this instead:

```
city=atlanta&zip=303
```

When you specify `style:deepObject` you will get:

```
origin[city]=atlanta&origin[zip]=303
```

The `spaceDelimited` and `pipeDelimited` style won't work with objects.

**Working without schema**

You can of cause work without a schema and define your `origin` query parameter of type `string`.
The documentation should explain exactly what you expect and a little example will help people to use your API.

I won't use that pattern for an open API, but this can be a workaround for an internal API.